# TypeScript Conditional Types and Type Guards

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements

I'm having some problems combining TypeScript's type guards and conditional types.  Consider:

```
export interface IThisThing {
    someProp: number;
}

export function isIThisThing(type: any): type is IThisThing { 
    return !!type.someProp;
}

export interface IThatThing {
    someOtherProp: string;
}

export function isIThatThing(type: any): type is IThatThing { 
    return !!type.someOtherProp;
}

function doAThing<T extends IThisThing | IThatThing>(
    data: T
): T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing {
    if (isIThisThing(data)) { 
        return data; // Type 'T & IThisThing' is not assignable to type 'T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing'.
    };
    return data; // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing'.
                 //   Type 'IThisThing | IThatThing' is not assignable to type 'T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing'.
                 //     Type 'IThisThing' is not assignable to type 'T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing'.
}
```

I'd expect the `doAThing` function to accept `IThisThing` or `IThatThing` and to return the same type as it receives.  Alas the compiler chokes with messages along the line of:

`Type 'T & IThisThing' is not assignable to type 'T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing'.`

Can someone set me straight? I feel I'm close but not quite getting it right.  I'm using the first example (which seems pretty similar) in this blog post: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript will not let you assign anything to a conditional type that still has free type parameter, it's just not supported. Your best bet is to have a signature with the generics and the conditional type and a simpler implementation signature that returns a union of the two possibilities

```
export interface IThisThing {
    someProp: number;
}

export function isIThisThing(type: any): type is IThisThing { 
    return !!type.someProp;
}

export interface IThatThing {
    someOtherProp: string;
}

export function isIThatThing(type: any): type is IThatThing { 
    return !!type.someOtherProp;
}

function doAThing<T extends IThisThing | IThatThing>(
    data: T
): T extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing
function doAThing(
    data: IThisThing | IThatThing
): IThisThing | IThatThing {
    if (isIThisThing(data)) { 
        return data;
    };
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by a "free type parameter"? I've googled around this but nothing is coming up..

Comment: Free in the sense that some type parameters are not know at the time of checking the function. In this case taht is `T`. You could assign a value to a conditional type if the type that the decision is based on is knows, so for example if the return type were `IThisThing  extends IThisThing ? IThisThing : IThatThing` you could have assign a compatible valeu to it.

Answer (score -3):

Just return `T`:

```
function doAThing<T extends IThisThing | IThatThing>(
    data: T
): T {
    if (isIThisThing(data)) { 
        return data
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```